Xlwings.LicenseError couldn't find an xlwings license key
I've installed the xlwings package and initially, it was functioning correctly. However, I'm now encountering an error stating "xlwings.LicenseError: Couldn't find an xlwings license key."
Code:
wb_output = xlwings.Book(os.path.join(self._output_folder_path, output_file_name))
for ws_output in wb_output.sheets:
    ws_output.range(str(ws_output.used_range.address)).api.Borders.Weight = 2
    ws_output.autofit()
    wb_output.save()
    wb_output.close()


Even after uninstalling and reinstalling xlwings, as well as downgrading to a previous version, I'm still encountering the same error. Also I try to upgrade but received message as requirement already satisfied.

Please share the full Traceback. The code doesn't use any xlwings PRO features, so this shouldn't trigger that error.

I have been checked somehow below line was added in a code and because of that it was showing error.
from xlwings.pro.reports.filters import header
